# Silverlight communication with a desktop process

Tags: silverlight

If there was a process on the user's desktop, would Silverlight be able to communicate with it? Is there a way to send messages from SL to a process that runs in the background and vice versa?

P.S. I am particularly interested in non-OOB SL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running OOB, with Elevated Trust would allow to open a socket connection to arbitrary destinations, including a local process hosting a listen socket. Otherwise I see no way how to do it.

Comment: Is it the same for SL5? I thought you can run an app in the browser with elevated trust.

Answer (score 0):

No. Silverlight will not allow you to deal with anything outside the web browser in non-OOB.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight -> JavaScript -> ActiveX
http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/17053/206880.aspx